# Excel formula: make the average depending on a cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to make a formula that turns in a VBA code that makes the average for column A even though there are some 0 there. I want to divide it by a the number in a cell that counts the objects in column A.

[image]

I used to use this formula, but it divides my sum incorrectly because I have 0's (I want to keep the 0's there):

```
=AVERAGE(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$10000)
```

Comment: Why you need `VBA`. you can do it by regular formula.

Comment: Because it is part of a bigger project, but still the formula doesn't work correctly

Comment: So `=sum(B:B)/count(A:A)`?

Comment: @eirikdaude I tried =sum(B:B)/E3 and it works now

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this, is to get the total of column B by using `sum(B:B)` (or a more specific range, if you want), and the amount of non-blank cells in column A by using `counta(A:A)` (in my comment I used `count` which only counts the amount of numbers in the range, `counta` should count all non-blank cells). You can then divide the former by the latter to get the number you are looking for, resulting in a formula looking something like

```
=SUM(B:B)/COUNTA(A:A)
```

If you already have the count of column A in a cell (e.g. E3), it's even simpler, just use something like

```
=SUM(B:B)/E3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AverageIf` for such a purpose, as you can see in my example:

```
Row/Column  A   B   C   D
         1
         2      2       =AVERAGE(B2:B5) => value 3
         3      4       =AVERAGEIF(B2:B5;"<>0") => value 4
         4      0
         5      6
```